# Can't install mkchromecast

Tags: linux-mint, chromecast

I'm trying to install [mkchromecast](http://mkchromecast.com/).

Following the instructions on the website, I first tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mkchromecast
```

Which returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mkchromecast
```

When this didn't work, I downloaded the .deb and tried this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i mkchromecast_0.3.6-3_all.deb
```

and got the following response:

```
Selecting previously unselected package mkchromecast.
(Reading database ... 244586 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mkchromecast_0.3.6-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking mkchromecast (0.3.6-3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mkchromecast:
 mkchromecast depends on python-flask; however:
  Package python-flask is not installed.
 mkchromecast depends on python-pychromecast; however:
  Package python-pychromecast is not installed.
 mkchromecast depends on python-psutil; however:
  Package python-psutil is not installed.
 mkchromecast depends on vorbis-tools (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package vorbis-tools is not installed.
 mkchromecast depends on lame (>= 3.99.0); however:
  Package lame is not installed.
 mkchromecast depends on flac (>= 1.3.0); however:
  Package flac is not installed.
 mkchromecast depends on python-pyqt5; however:
  Package python-pyqt5 is not installed.
 mkchromecast depends on youtube-dl; however:
  Package youtube-dl is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mkchromecast (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mkchromecast
```

A few Google searches led me to try:

```
sudo gdebi mkchromecast_0.3.6-3_all.deb
```

Which returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: python-pychromecast
```

So I downloaded the python-pychromecast.deb and:

```
sudo gdebi python-pychromecast_0.7.7-2_all.deb
```

But it seems the right version of python-protobuf is not installed:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: python-protobuf (>= 3)
```

However, if I run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-protobuf
```

It tells me it already is on the newest version:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-protobuf is already the newest version (2.6.1-1.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Therefore I forced an install of the right version with:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade protobuf==3.2.0
```

But this gives this response:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf==3.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/protobuf-3.2.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.9 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from protobuf==3.2.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from protobuf==3.2.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from setuptools->protobuf==3.2.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: packaging>=16.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from setuptools->protobuf==3.2.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf==3.2.0)
```

Which leads me to believe version >= 3 should be installed...

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's available in ubuntu, http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mkchromecast you don't have to try a deb package ..

Comment: So could you advise me on how to install Ubuntu packages on Mint?

Comment: What is the version of mint you're running?

Comment: Oh looks like this package is only available for ubuntu 16.10+

Comment: I'm running Linux Mint 18.1 Serena. It seems Mint 18.1 is based on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Oh you already opened an issue on github, it should work if you build it from source, just wait for the author to do that

Comment: Installing from source was successful, thanks for the advice! @daisy

Answer (score 1):

[Installing from source](https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast#from-sources) worked.

I also opened an issue on [github](https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast/issues/53), to which the creator responded:

*Correct me if I am wrong, but Mint is an Ubuntu's derivative. I imagine that from april ubuntu is having this app in their repos and therefore Mint will do as well (eventually). Please, feel free to close this report if you think that the issue is fixed. Thanks.*

Comment: Yes thats correct. It also has a Debian version. Not sure if the packages are interchangeable.